# How to Check IP Address of Subdomain

Tags: ip, subdomain

I'm sending XML from a client's site to an external server. This external server admin needs to verify the IP from the sender. We have the script working fine when sending from the main site (domain.com), but I am not sure when we are sending from a subdomain of the main site (sub.domain.com, getting an error currently). Is there a way to check the IP of a subdomain so I can give the admin the right IP address?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I've used the firefox extension 'IP Addresses and Domain Information' and am comparing the info from both domain.com and sub.domain.com and both look pretty much identical.

Comment: What have you tried? Is this via code, if so what language? Also have you looked at DNS resolution?

Comment: It's via PHP. I got the domain IP simply using command ping domain.com. Not sure how to get the subdomain IP though. Not sure about DNS resolution. I'm not really server savy unfortunately.

Comment: Ok so the same server might be handling the sub domain. What is the specific error then?

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to just use [nslookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) from a terminal

```
nslookup google.com
nslookup mail.google.com
```

From here it's trivial to write a script for this.  Here is a simple ruby example:

nslookup.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
domain = ARGV[0]
lookup = `nslookup #{domain}`.split("\n")
lines = lookup.select{ |line| line[/Address/] }[1..-1]
ips = lines.map{ |l| l.split('Address: ').last }
verb = ips.count > 1 ? 'are' : 'is'
  
puts "the IP addresses for #{domain} #{verb}:\n#{ips.join("\n")}"
```

Run from command line

```
ruby nslookup.rb api.stackoverflow.com 
# or just 
./nslookup.rb api.stackoverflow.com
```

should output something like

```
the IP addresses for stackoverflow.com are:
151.101.193.69
151.101.65.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.129.69
```

Answer (score 12):

I was also search on this topic then i have found a web site that helps me to find my subdomains IP address http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm

Comment: This is not a code answer but just a link to a lookup service.