# How do I get the IP address of this website?

Tags: windows, ping, nslookup

I want the IP address of https://sfbay.craigslist.org.

```
C:\Users\dude>ping https://sfbay.craigslist.org
Ping request could not find host https://sfbay.craigslist.org. 
Please check the name and try again.
```

So, I tried nslookup. None of the IP's in the output allow me to connect to the website using a browser. How do I get the right IP & connect ?

```
C:\Users\nisum>nslookup https://sfbay.craigslist.org/
Server:  cachens1.paetec.net
Address:  66.155.216.122

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    https://sfbay.craigslist.org/
Addresses:  104.239.198.84
          198.105.254.65
```

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser's debugging tools when loading the website... `Remote Address:208.82.237.146:443`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pings usually don't include the protocol. The command below worked for me.

`ping sfbay.craigslist.org`

Comment: Pinging cities.l.craigslist.org [208.82.237.130] with 32 bytes of data
Request timed out.

Comment: @testerjoe2: Doesn't time out for me.  (Though the IP is different.)  Maybe you're having network problems?  In any event, none of this is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

you can't access to this webSite with the adresse IP  because : this domain name is one of many subdomain that use one adresse IP : 208.82.237.2, for this you can just access with a Sub DNS. 
here is the main site with  details :

Details of 208.82.237.2

IP Address : 208.82.237.2

Location   : United States (95% accuracy)

Host Name  : cities.craigslist.org

you can use this link to test it : [www.hcidata.info](http://www.hcidata.info/)
also you can refer to this link : [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347650/how-to-check-ip-address-of-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

`Ifconfig sfbay.craigslist.org`

Or

`dig sfbay.craigslist.org`